# BeautifulSoup4 failing to read all of html. Site issue or BS4 issue?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-idle

I am trying to learn to use BS4 through the creation of a toy project in python to translate a different word using a variety of translators.

I installed BS4 and after importing it and urllib2 used this in the interactive console (IDLE):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://morfix.nana10.co.il/test').read())
```

it returns only until

```
<meta content="hyV6tXF5r6ClcgwEB4v4Q9SDIZU_isqlAONC5zk4b-8" name="google-site-verification"><meta content="CUQyCuYF1VpbyV7NX9gCZbe-D34iAwTtK9a5Y1YK3So" name="google-site-verification"><meta content="jKNHb3nlKVIBl0Z059KKo7mtvAVY9U4gbC+W10WdhWc=" name="verify-v1">
</meta></meta></meta></head></html>
```

of which the last line of end tags are not found in the site, which continues on for a while. In eclipse it works fine, and gives the whole html of the site.

Is this a limitation of IDLE, that it can only print out a certain length string etc? Because i tried it on another fairly long site and it worked fine. Or is it something else?

Comment: `print urllib2.urlopen('http://morfix.nana10.co.il/test').read()` should answer your question.

Comment: Clarification: I'm tired. But that said, it looks to still come down to either BS4, or idle meets BS4, because printing out the plain html gives what it should. Which makes sense...

Comment: I ran your code in IDLE and did not have any problem.  The entire page was read and passed to BeautifulSoup, which had no problem parsing it.

Comment: I doubt that it is the same issue but bs4/lxml had a bug http://stackoverflow.com/a/9849760/4279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is, but this is to show that it's not what you think it is.

Run from within IDLE.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://morfix.nana10.co.il/test').read())

>>> print soup

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<base href="http://morfix.nana10.co.il/"/>
<script src="js/search2/performanceCounter.js?ver=280512" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var oLoadCounter = null;

            try
            {                                           
                oLoadCounter = new PerfomanceCounter('load',true);              
            }catch(e)
            {
            }                                         
        </script>
<meta content="hyV6tXF5r6ClcgwEB4v4Q9SDIZU_isqlAONC5zk4b-8" name="google-site-verification"><meta content="CUQyCuYF1VpbyV7NX9gCZbe-D34iAwTtK9a5Y1YK3So" name="google-site-verification"><meta content="jKNHb3nlKVIBl0Z059KKo7mtvAVY9U4gbC+W10WdhWc=" name="verify-v1">
<link href="images/MobileLandingPage/icon.png" rel="image_src">
<style type="text/css">
        @import "styles/search2_general.css?ver=280512";
        @import "styles/search2_he.css?ver=280512";
        @import "styles/mobileAppsModalPopup.css?ver=280512";
    </style>
<meta content="he" http-equiv="Content-Language"/>
<meta content="תרגום של המילה test על ידי אתר מורפיקס, השירות החינמי המוביל לתרגום אנגלית עברית, הכולל הקראת מילים וביטויים, משפטי דוגמה, ניקוד בעברית, ניתוח נטיות בעברית ובאנגלית ועוד." name="description"><meta content="test,מילון, תרגום אנגלי עברי עיברי, מילון אנגלי עברי עיברי" name="keywords"><link href="MorfixSearch.xml" rel="search" title="מילון מורפיקס" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"/><link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/AjaxAutoComplete/AutoComplete.js?ver=280512" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="js/AjaxAutoComplete/AutoComplete.css?ver=280512" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/search2/global.js?ver=280512" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="external/embedded/mobileapps/js/mobileAppsPopup.js?ver=280512" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        oMobileAppsPopup.initialize({ mode: 'modal'});
    </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            oSearch.changeDefaultSearchPage("http://morfix.nana10.co.il/");
            oStuff.changeKeyboardPage("http://morfix.nana10.co.il/keyboard2.aspx?source=site");
            oDynamicAds.changeMarginLeftAdDirection('right');
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
           try
            {                           
                oStuff.oFeatures.oPerformance.bMonitor = true;                                              
            }catch(e)
            {
            }                                         
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">                                                             
                oSearch.onLoad(90,'transmit performance', function() { 
                   setTimeout('oPerformance.transmitPerformance();',5000);
                });                                                 
            </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {                                              
           $("[id$=searchField]").autocomplete("http://dictionary.melingo.com/autocomplete/",                                   
            {
            delay:400,
            minChars:3,
            matchSubset:1,
            matchContains:1,
            cacheLength:0,
            cacheActive:false,
            width:443,
            OffsetX: 75,
            offsetHeight: 44,
            maxItemsToShow:10

            });     
        });             
     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {                                              
           $("[id$=searchField]").keypress(function()
                                        {
                                            imposeMaxLength(this,50);
                                        });  
           $("[id$=searchField]").blur(function()
                                        {
                                            imposeMaxLength(this,50);
                                        });                                                
           $("[id$=searchField]").bind('input paste',function(eventObject)
                                        {
                                            imposeMaxLength(this,50);
                                        });                             
        });     
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

      var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
      _gaq.push( 
          ['_setAccount', 'UA-5815264-1'], 
          ['_setDetectFlash', false],
          ['_trackPageview']
        );            

      (function() { 
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
      })(); 

    </script>
<!-- (C)2000-2011 Gemius SA - gemiusAudience / nana10.co.il / morfix -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    &lt;!--//--&gt;&lt;![CDATA[//&gt;&lt;!--
        var pp_gemius_identifier = new String('AqJAUqeLz8WkBf708M4kAJdRTO4I5.hWHKupK3C.n2b.l7');
    //--&gt;&lt;!]]&gt;
    </script>
<script src="http://common.nana10.co.il/JScript/GeneralModules/Banner/xgemius.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://storage.conduit.com/PS/morfix/tbinstall/tbInstall.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta content="197722006971114" property="fb:app_id"/>
<meta content="100000681777777" property="fb:admins"/>
<meta content="100000681777777" property="fb:moderator"/>
<meta content="http://morfix.nana10.co.il/default.aspx" property="og:url"/>
<script src="js/Facebook.js?ver=280512" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>
    מילון מורפיקס – Morfix Dictionary  - test
</title></link></meta></meta></link></meta></meta></meta></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var CM8Server = "nana10.checkm8.com";
            var CM8Cat = "pid48.affiliates.morfix.search_page";
            var CM8Profile = "";
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                oStuff.oFeatures.oSound.bEnable = true;
                oStuff.oFeatures.oSound.SoundManagerPath = './SoundManager';
           </script>
<script src="SoundManager/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/search2/sound/flashblock.js?ver=280512" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/search2/flash/detectflash.js?ver=280512" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="underHeaderAdv">
<div class="adv_ph">
<center>
<div id="_ctl0_frmResultsPageUnderHeaderLeft1" style="overflow:hidden;padding:0;margin:0;width:780px;height:90px;"></div>
</center>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="height:5px;"></div>
<div id="_ctl0_headerToolBarContainer" style="overflow:hidden;padding:0;margin:0;margin-left:auto ;margin-right:auto ;width:950px;height:36px;">
</div>
<div id="page">
<div id="header2">
<div class="first_row">
<div class="google">
<div class="googleLogo"></div>
<form action="search.aspx" id="cse-search-box" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Google', 'Search', 'Milon search page']);">
<input name="cx" type="hidden" value="partner-pub-0096668058692956:f679gw5cgah"/>
<input name="cof" type="hidden" value="FORID:11"/>
<input name="ie" type="hidden" value="UTF-8"/>
<input name="hl" type="hidden" value="he"/>
<input id="queryField" name="q" size="27" style="" type="text"/>
<input class="GoogleSubmitButton" name="sa" type="submit" value=""/>
</form>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="right_menu">
<div class="right_menu_row">
<div class="itemDouble button morfixApps" id="mobileAppsBtn" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','To page: mobile applications (Upper Menu)'); return oMobileAppsPopup.startTimedoutModalPopup({url:'external/Embedded/MobileApps/MobileAppsDownload2.htm'});" onmouseout="this.className='itemDouble button morfixApps'" onmouseover="this.className='morfixAppsOver button'">
<em style="vertical-align:top;">אפליקציות להורדה <b>חינם!</b></em>
</div>
<div class="itemDouble button" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','To page: storefix (Upper Menu)'); return oBrowser.openURL('https://www.facebook.com/morfix?sk=app_144440148901844','_blank');" onmouseout="this.className='itemDouble button'" onmouseover="this.className='itemDoubleOver button'"><img alt="storefix" src="../images/hive/storefixbtn.png"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="right_menu_row">
<div class="item button" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','To page: blog (Upper Menu)'); return oBrowser.openURL('http://blog.ravmilim.co.il/','_blank');" onmouseout="this.className='item button'" onmouseover="this.className='itemOver button'" style="font-size:9pt">
                            בלוג רב-מילים
                        </div>
<div class="item button" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','To page: download toolbar (Upper Menu)'); return oBrowser.openURL('http://downloadmytoolbar.com/morfix/lp2/','_blank');" onmouseout="this.className='item button'" onmouseover="this.className='itemOver button'">סרגל-כלים</div>
<div class="item button" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','To page: Nakdan (Upper Menu)'); return oBrowser.openURL('http://www.melingo.co.il/nakdan/naerr.asp','_blank');" onmouseout="this.className='item button'" onmouseover="this.className='itemOver button'">נקדן טקסט</div>
<div class="item button" id="_ctl0_divChangeLangHiveBtn" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','To page: english version (Upper Menu)');return oBrowser.openURL('http://morfix.nana10.co.il/en/test')" onmouseout="this.className='item button'" onmouseover="this.className='itemOver button'" style="color:#06377A">English
                        </div>
</div>
<div class="right_menu_row">
<div class="item button" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','To page: Ravmilim (Upper Menu)'); return oBrowser.openURL('http://www.ravmilim.co.il','_blank');" onmouseout="this.className='item button'" onmouseover="this.className='itemOver button'">
                            רב-מילים</div>
<div class="item button" id="_ctl0_divMakeMyHomepage" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','Make Morfix my homepage'); return oStuff.makeHomePage('http://morfix.nana10.co.il/');" onmouseout="this.className='item button'" onmouseover="this.className='itemOver button'" style="font-size:9pt">הפוך לדף הבית
                        </div>
<div class="item button" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','To page: email us (Upper Menu)');window.open('http://morfix.nana10.co.il/pages/contactus', 'morfix_emailus', 'width=600,height=600,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,left=80,top=60');return false;" onmouseout="this.className='item button'" onmouseover="this.className='itemOver button'" style="">כתבו לנו
                        </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="mobileAppsPopUp">
<div id="mobileAppsPopUpContent">
<div id="mobileAppsPopUpCloseButton"></div>
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="external/Embedded/MobileApps/MobileAppsDownload2.htm"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div class="second_row">
<div class="nanaAlign">
<div class="nana_logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="logo_ph">
<div class="logo" onclick="oBrowser.openURL('http://morfix.nana10.co.il/')" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
<div class="faceBookLikes">
<div id="_ctl0_frmLogoHeaderLeft1" style="overflow:visible;padding:0;margin:0;width:100px;height:21px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<form action="default.aspx?hl=&amp;q=test" id="aspnetForm" method="post" name="aspnetForm" onsubmit="return false;">
<input id="originalSearch" name="originalSearch" type="hidden" value="test"/>
<input id="isC" name="isC" type="hidden" value="0"/>
<input id="q" name="q" type="hidden" value="test"/>
<input id="source" name="source" type="hidden" value="milon"/>
<input id="__VIEWSTATE" name="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden" value="/wEPDwUKLTEwNTI0MDMxN2QYAgUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFEl9jdGwwOnRyYW5zbGF0ZUJ0bgUuX2N0bDA6bWFpbkNvbnRlbnQ6dGl0bGVDb250cm9sOnZpZXdDb2xsb2NhdGlvbg8PZGZk/g1bbc4Dh0CUEZ6GxJzIGld9d48="/>
<script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_above_translations_results', sHtmlContent : '&lt;!-- Morfix_HE_Sentences --&gt;&lt;div id=&#39;div-gpt-ad-1334224791925-0&#39; style=&#39;width:468px; height:60px;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: 'googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(&#39;div-gpt-ad-1334224791925-0&#39;); });', nWidth : 468, nHeight : 60});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_popUnder', sHtmlContent : '&lt;div id=&quot;CM8ShowAd_RichInline&quot; title=&quot;RichInline&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: '', nWidth : 10, nHeight : 10});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_frmLogoHeaderLeft1', sHtmlContent : '&lt;iframe src=&quot;//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.morfix.co.il&amp;amp;send=false&amp;amp;layout=button_count&amp;amp;width=100&amp;amp;show_faces=false&amp;amp;action=like&amp;amp;colorscheme=light&amp;amp;font&amp;amp;height=21&amp;amp;appId=210469539042747&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; style=&quot;border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;&quot; allowTransparency=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: '', nWidth : 100, nHeight : 21});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_rowSearch_subrow1_col3_results', sURL : 'external/ads/nana/rowsearch_subrow1_col3_results.htm', sType : 'div', nWidth : 300, nHeight : 250});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_row1col3_results', sHtmlContent : '&lt;!-- Morfix_HE_Bottom_Row01Col03 --&gt;&lt;div id=&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-2&#39; style=&#39;width:300px; height:300px;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: 'googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-2&#39;); });', nWidth : 300, nHeight : 250});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_row2col3_results', sHtmlContent : '&lt;!-- Morfix_HE_Bottom_Row02Col03 --&gt;&lt;div id=&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-5&#39; style=&#39;width:300px; height:300px;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: 'googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-5&#39;); });', nWidth : 300, nHeight : 250});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_row3col3_results', sHtmlContent : '&lt;!-- Morfix_HE_Bottom_Row03Col03 --&gt;&lt;div id=&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-8&#39; style=&#39;width:300px; height:400px;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: 'googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-8&#39;); });', nWidth : 300, nHeight : 400});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_row1col1', sHtmlContent : '&lt;!-- Morfix_HE_Bottom_Row01Col01 --&gt;&lt;div id=&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-0&#39; style=&#39;width:300px; height:300px;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: 'googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-0&#39;); });', nWidth : 300, nHeight : 250});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_row2col1', sHtmlContent : '&lt;!-- Morfix_HE_Bottom_Row02Col01 --&gt;&lt;div id=&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-3&#39; style=&#39;width:300px; height:300px;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: 'googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-3&#39;); });', nWidth : 300, nHeight : 250});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_row3col1', sHtmlContent : '&lt;!-- Morfix_HE_Bottom_Row03Col01 --&gt;&lt;div id=&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-6&#39; style=&#39;width:300px; height:400px;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: 'googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-6&#39;); });', nWidth : 300, nHeight : 400});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_row1col2', sHtmlContent : '&lt;div id=&quot;CM8ShowAd_Box_250x250_1&quot; title=&quot;Box_250x250_1&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: '', nWidth : 250, nHeight : 250});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_row2col2', sHtmlContent : '&lt;!-- Morfix_HE_Bottom_Row02Col02 --&gt;&lt;div id=&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-4&#39; style=&#39;width:250px; height:250px;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: 'googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-4&#39;); });', nWidth : 250, nHeight : 250});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_row3col2', sHtmlContent : '&lt;!-- Morfix_HE_Bottom_Row03Col02 --&gt;&lt;div id=&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-7&#39; style=&#39;width:250px; height:400px;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: 'googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(&#39;div-gpt-ad-1330963433824-7&#39;); });', nWidth : 250, nHeight : 400});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_frmUnderSearchBoxLeft1', sHtmlContent : '&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: '', nWidth : 468, nHeight : 60});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdvHighPriority({sID : '_ctl0_frmResultsPageUnderHeaderLeft1', sHtmlContent : '&lt;div id=&quot;CM8ShowAd_Plazma_720x300&quot; title=&quot;Plazma_720x300&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id=&quot;CM8ShowAd_Mainstrip_780x150&quot; title=&quot;Mainstrip_780x150&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id=&quot;CM8ShowAd_Top_728x90&quot; title=&quot;Top_728x90&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: '', nWidth : 780, nHeight : 90});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_frmMarginLeftResultsTop1', sHtmlContent : '&lt;div id=&quot;CM8ShowAd_Ozen_160x600&quot; title=&quot;Ozen_160x600&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', sType : 'div', sScriptContent: '', nWidth : 160, nHeight : 600});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdv({sID : '_ctl0_frmMarginRightResultsTop1', sURL : 'external/ads/nana/margin_right_result.htm', sType : 'div', nWidth : 160, nHeight : 600});</script><script type="text/javascript">oAdv.registerAdvHighPriority({sID : '_ctl0_headerToolBarContainer', sURL : 'http://common.nana10.co.il/GeneralModules/Category/default.asp?sid=27&amp;pid=48&amp;CategoryID=27&amp;TypeID=1000&amp;ABG=c03&amp;AFR=fff&amp;BG=F4F4F4&amp;FR=2&amp;StripBG=c03&amp;Logo=2', sType : 'div', nWidth : 950, nHeight : 36});</script>
<input id="__EVENTVALIDATION" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" type="hidden" value="/wEWAwLF0uiPDQLExriHBgK1vsKpCCf/JKPBwLmLLUs6eTqpIuD8QTIh"/>
<div id="main">
<div class="row">
<div class="colspan_1_2">
<div id="search">
<div class="searchbox_ph">
<div class="searchbox_bg">
<div class="container">
<div class="title">
<div class="description">הקלידו מילה, ביטוי, מושג או משפט קצר, בעברית או באנגלית</div>
</div>
<textarea class="searchField english" id="_ctl0_searchField" name="_ctl0:searchField" onkeyup="oUI.changeSearchFieldDir();" style="overflow:hidden;">test</textarea>
<div class="keyboard_container button" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','Show virtual keyboard');oStuff.openKeyboard();" title="לחצו לקבלת מקלדת וירטואלית עברית">
<div class="keyboard"></div>
<div style="color:Gray;font-size:7pt;">מקלדת</div>
</div>
<div class="buttons_container">
<div class="action_buttons">
<div class="translate button" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','milon search'); return oSearch.performSearch($('[id$=searchField]').val());" title="לחצו לתרגום מילים מעברית לאנגלית ולהפך">
<input border="0" id="_ctl0_translateBtn" name="_ctl0:translateBtn" style="display:none;" type="image"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="features_menu">
<div class="search button" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','Open Last search list');oUI.changeToWait(this);oBrowser.openURL('http://morfix.nana10.co.il/pages/lastsearches');" title="לחצו לקבלת רשימת מילים אחרונות – לחזרה ולשינון"></div>
<div class="hagrel button" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','Request Gesture');oStuff.executeGesture(this);" title="לחצו להגרלת ערך מעניין מויקיפדיה – להרחבת הידע הכללי"></div>
<div class="facebookCommentsLink" id="_ctl0_facebookCommentsLinkPlaceHolder_facebookCommentsLinkRef" onclick="oStuff.scrollTo('facebookComments')">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="result_ph">
<div class="warning_line content" id="reachedMaxCharsLimit" style="display:none">
<div class="content">
                                ניתן להקליד עד 50 תווים בלבד                            
                            </div>
</div>
<div class="box584_m">
<div style="padding: 10px 10px 0 10px">
<script type="text/javascript">
            oFacebook.setFacebookIdURL('http://morfix.nana10.co.il/default.aspx?q=test&amp;source=Milon');  
        </script>
<!-- flash for sound code -->
<div>
<div id="noFlashDiv">
<div class="warning_line noFlash button" onclick="oBrowser.openURL('http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/','_blank');"><div class="content">על-מנת להשתמש באפשרות השמעת מילים עליכם להתקין פלאש. <span class="link">לחצו כאן</span> להתקנה</div></div>
</div>
<div class="warning_line" id="blockFlashDiv"><div class="content" style="margin-top:2px">על-מנת להשתמש באפשרות השמעת מילים עליכם ללחוץ על סרטון הפלאש שמופיע מתחת להודעה זו</div></div>
<div class="swf-default" id="sm2-container" style=""></div>
</div>
<h1 class="box_title">תוצאות תרגום עבור: test</h1>
<div id="_ctl0_mainContent_milonResultControl_ResultContainer">
<div class="translate_box_en box heWord0">
<div class="title_ph">
<div class="word_ph translation_en">
<span class="word">test</span>
<span class="diber">noun</span>
</div>
<div class="translation translation_he heTrans">מִבְחָן, מִבְדָּק, טֶסְט; תַּבְחִין </div>
<div class="translation translation_he heSoundTrans"> </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="goodies_ph">
<div class="goody">
<a class="button speaker imageSoundUnclicked" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','Play sound');oSound.playSound('http://morfix.nana10.co.il/getwave.aspx?word=test&amp;ext=.wav&amp;source=site&amp;isEnglish=true')" style="cursor:wait;"></a>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="extra_data">
<div class="inflection_ph" id="inflDiv0">
<div class="english translation_header">
                                            test
                                        </div>
<div dir="ltr" style="position:relative">
                                            test: <em class="english english_font">יחיד</em>;
                                            tests: <em class="english english_font">רבים</em>;

                                        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="result_seperator"></div>
<div class="translate_box_en box heWord1">
<div class="title_ph">
<div class="word_ph translation_en">
<span class="word">test</span>
<span class="diber">verb</span>
</div>
<div class="translation translation_he heTrans">בָּדַק, בָּחַן </div>
<div class="translation translation_he heSoundTrans"> </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="goodies_ph">
<div class="goody">
<a class="button speaker imageSoundUnclicked" onclick="oStuff.gaLog('UserAction','Play sound');oSound.playSound('http://morfix.nana10.co.il/getwave.aspx?word=test&amp;ext=.wav&amp;source=site&amp;isEnglish=true')" style="cursor:wait;"></a>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="extra_data">
<div class="inflection_ph" id="inflDiv1">
<div class="english translation_header">
                                            to test
                                        </div>
<div dir="ltr" style="position:relative">
                                          tested: <em class="english english_font">עבר</em>;
                                          test / tests: <em class="english english_font">הווה</em>;
                                          is testing: <em class="english english_font">הווה ממושך</em>;
                                          has tested: <em class="english english_font">הווה מושלם</em>;
                                          will test: <em class="english english_font">עתיד</em>;

                                        </div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="height:5px;"></div>
<div id="SampleSentencesTitle">דוגמאות שימוש:</div>
<div style="height:3px;"></div>
```

Snipped due to maximum answer length.

Comment: Thanks for the verification. Im running a 64bit windows build, python 2.7, and consistently get the correct html from urllib2, and the cut off version from BS4. But only in IDLE, not eclipse. Go Figure!

Comment: @commentator8:  Then I'm stumped.  I'd take the lazy way out and just not use IDLE.

Comment: It was just for testing purposes, i am using eclipse in main. Thanks for the help!