# Weird Unicode Error. - Zen Cart software

Tags: php, unicode, zen-cart

So, I inherited this project and I'm coming across this weird Unicode error the website is rendering: `ï»¿` Now, when I use the Developer Tool Kit inside the Zen cart admin panel to find where this error is, it says the location is: `Line #0 : ï»¿<?php`, how could this happen? If I knew where the error was being produced I would post a code snippet but, I honestly have no idea. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you searched your php files for that string?

Comment: I have, that's why I'm displaying where the error is coming up. The odd thing is it's saying it's being produced on line 0 which makes no sense because, there is no line 0.

Comment: It looks like a "shadow" character somewhere within a PHP file. As this post suggest (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845976/whats-%C3%AF-sign-at-the-beginning-of-php-source-file), you should try to save all files as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: You know what, I was notified by Visual Studio ultimate 2013 to save it as a UTF-8 I wonder if that was happened. Do you know how I would convert it to UTF-8 without BOM on Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ivan Gabriele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2736233/ivan-gabriele) is correct it is referred to as a shadow character: [What's ï»¿ sign at the beginning of my source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845976/whats-%C3%AF-sign-at-the-beginning-of-php-source-file)

The why to resolve the issue in Visual Studio is also posted here: [UTF-8 without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom)