# ASCII characters sending email to SendGrid

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am using the SendGrid API to send some emails.  When the emails show up in SendGrids back-end it says they were dropped and couldn't be sent.  However, the emails that were dropped have this before them:  ï»¿

So, I am assuming when I sent the email via the API these characters made it in there somehow?

Is there a PHP function I should call on the email before I send it over to them?

Comment: Check how your saving the file, its BOM (Byte Order Mark)

Comment: Hi @LawrenceCherone I am not saving it. I am pulling emails from my DB and then putting them into code to send them to SendGrid via their API.  (Unless I am misunderstanding you.)

Comment: Are you using a view/template of sorts?

Comment: This page is running within wordpress.

Comment: Ok, how do you construct the email template?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845976/whats-%C3%AF-sign-at-the-beginning-of-my-source-file, basically you need to find the file which constructs the email in a nice form and not just text, and then take out the BOM and save without BOM.

Comment: `$to = new SendGrid\Email($thename, $email);
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", $content);
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", $htmlcontent);
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163749/discussion-between-craig-and-lawrence-cherone).

Comment: Where is `$htmlcontent` created? If its all in the db, then remove the BOM from the database value.